# Hiding keyboard breaks segue of TableView

Tags: ios, swift

```
let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(Viewcontroller.dismissKeyboard))
            view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    func dismissKeyboard() {
            view.endEditing(true)
        }
```

My code that hides keyboard.

But this code also breaks segue of TableView.

Is there any other way to hide keyboard by touching somewhere of the view?

Answer (score 0):

If are you sure your tap gesture recognizer working fine. You should use the `resignFirstResponder` method of your textField. Think about this if your users tapped your textField keyboard will show and if they tapped the outside of the textView somewhere in view. TapGestureRecognizer should be trigged with `texfield.resignFirstResponder()` method. So your keyboard should be hidden.

If it doesn't work. Please **test** your **tapGestureRecognizer** method with `print` something.